# Sharepoint Online Site Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search-results

I am getting 2 different results from 2 search fields on Sharepoint Online. The 1st picture was searched via Find a file on the document library, 2nd was via Search this Site

[image]
 [image]

Any reason why i am not getting all 3 results when searching via Search this Site?

The Customer Number column is indexed too

Comment: hi, just an update, i figured out that this is because by default that Show Duplicates have been disabled. I can find the other missing document now once i enabled Don't Remove Duplicates. The only thing i don't like is the fact that you have to use Search this site then choose search Everything. Is there a way to change this so that i can find all the data in the Document Library instead of EVERYTHING?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to search within a document library, I suggest you use "Find a file" to do that.

Or, you can create a search result source for the library, then create a custom search result page for it.

There are two articles for your reference:
[SharePoint Online: How to create a result source and use custom result source in content search web part](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37407.sharepoint-online-how-to-create-a-result-source-and-use-custom-result-source-in-content-search-web-part.aspx)
[How to configure result search web part to show documents from in specific Document library?](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-configure-result-search-web-part-to-show-documents-from-in-specific-document-library/)

Comment: Thanks @Kally_MSFT i think i figured out my issue regarding the search results. I understand that there isnt alot you guys and go on with since i redacted the screenshot. Basically for one of the entries i have the file name the same as the customer name. Sharepoint sees that a duplicate for some reason. As soon as i change the file name, i was able to search / find all 3 documents

Comment: hi @Kally_MSFT hope you dont mind me asking, is there a way to enable the search results via the "Search this site" function to enable users to modify a document's properties?